# What are the specific steps to enable the ZeroMQ extension for PHP 7.3?

Tags: php, configuration, zeromq, php-extension, php-ini

I am trying to enable the ZeroMQ extension for PHP on Windows.

I've got a PHP 7.3 ZTS installation on my x64 Windows 10. Since the official [zeromq/php-zmq](https://github.com/zeromq/php-zmq) is no longer maintained, I've tried using the [latest release from alexat/php-zmq](https://github.com/alexat/php-zmq/releases/tag/1.1.4), but to no avail. This is what I tried doing:

1. Download and extract [the latest ZeroMQ release](https://zeromq.org/download/#windows).
2. Copy `libzmq.dll` to `php7.3.x` *and* to `php7.3.x/ext`.
3. Download and extract the php-zmq extension.
4. Copy `php_zmq.dll` to `php7.3.x/ext`.
5. Append `extension=zmq` to my `php.ini` (which I've gotten from `php --ini`).

Subsequent `php -v` tells me that `PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zmq' (tried: php7.3.x\ext\zmq (...), php7.3.x\ext\php_zmq.dll (The specified module could not be found.))` (emphasis mine). I have also tried modifying `extension_dir`, but it does point to the correct directory.

Prompted by the startup warning, I've tried altering `php.ini` to `extension=zmq123456`, which certainly did not exist in the extension directory, however PHP greeted me (correctly, this time around) with the same warning.

Some have suggested mine to be a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412911), however in my case PHP is **incorrectly** acting like the extension library `php_zmq.dll` is not even present where expected, while **it clearly and verifiably is**. Can you see the problem and perhaps describe comprehensively, how I should properly enable the ZeroMQ extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP ZMQ Extension: Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412911/php-zmq-extension-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: @Rain, no, it doesn't. I've tried various combinations of DLL versions, but I have little idea about just how dynamically-loaded libraries work in terms of dependencies. Maybe I should research a bit in that direction, to shine some light on the way these PHP extensions and compiled libraries are set up.

Comment: get rid of the lib prefix. libzmq.dll and php_zmq.dll should be zmq.dll

Comment: If that doesn't work, check the dll with dependency walker to see if you are missing runtime libs.

Comment: @AlexBarker None worked. I'd checked with the dependency walker previously also, however I am not quite sure what I am supposed to look for, since upon scanning the DLL of another, working, extension, the walker showed twice as many red error messages.

Comment: The PHP downloads from windows.php.net contain deplister.exe; so just run `deplister php_zmq.dll` to see which other DLLs it requires, and whether these can be found.

Comment: @cmb The deplister is a really neat tool. I learned that the library needed to have a very specific name to be found in the PHP directory. `php -m` now lists the module as `zmq`, and I am able to use the extension's userland API almost flawlessly — only when I try to use any of the documented messaging patterns, no error is produced when publishing/requesting/sending while the receiving end hangs indefinitely and no message goes through. I have no idea where to look for errors in this case. Is there a place PHP logs internal errors that may be occuring?

Comment: have you found any solution?